# Reloading page Angular html5mode with base as subdirectory

Tags: angularjs, reload, subdirectory

I'm wondering what I've done incorrectly or what I'm missing. I'm trying to use html5mode with my base href as a subdirectory. If I go to a route off of that base and reload, the page tries to jump back to before the subdirectory.

If that doesn't make any sense, let me show you how I've configured...

In my app.js file I have set:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

In my index.html file, in my  tag I've set:

```
<base href="/subdirectory/">
```

Thus, if I navigate to http://url.com/subdirectory all is good.

If I then click a link to visit http://url.com/subdirectory/subpage, all is good.

However, if I RELOAD the subpage, OR, if I try to navigate directly to that subpage, it will not render. In fact, I believe the browser thinks it's trying to start back at http://url.com instead of starting from http://url.com/subdirectory/

Can someone who's experienced a similar problem explain a solution to this?

I've been banging my head against the wall. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you haven't configured server properly

Comment: @charlietfl Forgive me if I say I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to server configuration. I've looked up some information on .htaccess files but I'm not having an easy time with it. Instead of just commenting that I haven't done something properly, (because that's probably obvious,) do you think you can offer a solution and/or point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: couldn't make suggestions because different types of servers use different configuration systems. Also we don't know what else you have on server. Angular is using what server sees as virtual directories if you set `html5Mode`. If you don't set that it will use hash and have no server impact

Comment: Should be able to research this and make attempts to set up htaccess to serve the angular app entry point when requested directory doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your server to redirect all requests to `http://url.com/subdirectory/subpage` to the same location as `http://url.com/subdirectory/` points to.

Comment: Can you please direct me on how to accomplish this? I'm a beginner when it comes to server config. Thank you!

Comment: What server are you using? Apache?

Answer (score 0):

So this was the solution.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /subdirectory/index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```